# What was Carter Burke's job for "the Company" in Aliens?

Tags: alien-franchise, aliens-1986

Burke seems to be a pretty involved guy for Weyland-Yutani Corp. He acts as point of contact/liaison with Ripley at Gateway Station, sends a message to the colony on LV-426 to investigate the 'Space Jockey' ship (and seems to have the potential to intercept or interfere with communications, etc between the colony and the Company) and accompanies the Colonial Marines and Ripley to the planet.

**What was his actual role for Weyland-Yutani?**

Comment: I always thought of him as the "on the ground" rep of the Company, making sure the latter's interests are served. I don't know if there's more of a background to the character

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We see Carter J. Burke's [business card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwFxG.jpg) in *Aliens*.

> Special Projects Director in the Special Services Division of Weyland Yutani (Space) Corporation.

A high-quality replica of the original prop is shown below.

[image: Carter Burke's business card, stamped with the above role, and a black and yellow logo]

One assumes that he's (partially) responsible for special projects like terraforming planets.

Comment: For the record, I presume the J is for Judas.

Comment: ask the question, although if you don't know it.....

Comment: would this position give him access to carry out your suggestion from my last question

Comment: @Seamusthedog - I don't see why not

Comment: I'd say terraforming would not be a particularly "special" project for W-Y corporation, as Burke mentions in relation to the atmospheric processor: "we manufacture those by the way". I'd assumed it meant "special" as in "special forces" i.e. covert industrial espionage, illegal importation of dangerous xenomorphs and similar shenanigans.